# Trouble downloading media off DJI Inspire 1 using Android SDK

Tags: android, dji-sdk

I am currently writing an Android application that downloads all the images off an Inspire 1. I am using the latest version of the SDK (v3.2.1). I am using the DJIPlaybackManager to do this. However, I am encountering a problem with downloading all the images.

Whenever I run the code below, I get "No files selected" even though right above it I think I select all the files on the SD Card. This error is thrown in the onError method in the CameraFileDownloadCallback. The error returned from selectAllFiles() is null, so I believe that means it selected correctly. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong? I have tried many things but nothing seems to work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
private static String TAG = "MediaManager";

public static void downloadAllMedia(final Context mContext) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Downloading media...");
    final String fileDirPath = mContext.getFilesDir().getPath();
    DJIBaseProduct product = DJIDemoApplication.getProductInstance();
    if (product != null && product.isConnected()) {
        if (product instanceof DJIAircraft) {
            final DJICamera camera = product.getCamera();
            if (camera != null) {
                camera.setCameraMode(DJICameraSettingsDef.CameraMode.Playback, new DJIBaseComponent.DJICompletionCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(DJIError djiError) {
                        if (djiError == null) {
                            final DJIPlaybackManager playbackManager = camera.getPlayback();
                            DJICameraError enterPreviewModeError = playbackManager.enterMultiplePreviewMode();
                            if(enterPreviewModeError != null) {
                                Log.e(TAG, "Failed to enter mutliple preview mode");
                            }
                            DJICameraError enterEditModeError = playbackManager.enterMultipleEditMode();
                            if(enterEditModeError != null) {
                                Log.e(TAG, "Failed to enter multiple edit mode: " + enterEditModeError.getDescription());
                                return;
                            }
                            DJIError selectFilesError = playbackManager.selectAllFiles();
                            if (selectFilesError != null) {
                                Log.e(TAG, "Failed to select files on device: " + selectFilesError.getDescription());
                                return;
                            } else {
                                Log.d(TAG, "Successfully selected all media");
                            }
                            playbackManager.downloadSelectedFiles(new File(fileDirPath), new DJIPlaybackManager.CameraFileDownloadCallback() {
                                @Override
                                public void onStart() {
                                    Log.d(TAG, "Starting fetch of media");
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onEnd() {
                                    Log.d(TAG, "Finished downloading media");
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onError(Exception e) {
                                    Log.e(TAG, "Failed downloading media: " + e.getMessage());
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onProgressUpdate(int i) {
                                    Log.d(TAG, "Media download from drone: " + i + "%");
                                }
                            });
                        } else {
                            Log.e(TAG, "Could not set the Camera mode to playback");
                        }
                    }
                });
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "Camera is not available");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [link](https://github.com/dji-sdk/Mobile-SDK-Android/blob/fd9d550f7c5fe8d02a37f7d50fb01fe149d565ee/Sample%20Code/app/src/main/java/com/dji/sdk/sample/camera/PlaybackDownloadView.java) for equivalent code in DJI Sample Code. Once you download and run it, you can modify line number 112 to

`mPlaybackManager.selectAllFiles();`

Once you run this code press the middle button `1st Photo` to select all the photos and press `Download`.

This is confirmed to have working with DJI Product.

Comment: I have seen that example, but unfortunately it is for an older version of the SDK, so it is structured quite a bit differently (the select methods have callbacks vs now they seem like one-off statements). It seems that DJI has changed a bit in their SDK.

Comment: The link I sent is for version 3.2.1. As far as I know this is the latest public one. Which one are you looking at?